# how can i change text of TextView in ListView when we click the Button?

Tags: android

**I have a ListView with a Button and a TextView and i want to change text of TextView when i click in Button. I handle the click and when i click the Button `android:onClick="myClickHandler"` i change the text value of TextView but the problem is when i scroll the ListView i found the same text in other cells in ListView. how can i resolve this problem? 
 tanx a lot.**
this is the method to handle click

```
public void myClickHandler(View v) 
{

    //get the row the clicked button is in
    LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
    TextView child = (TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(1);
    child.setText("bma bla");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refresh the listadapter and listview adapter  every change at the same time. I think it will help you.

Comment: tanx for the answer. i will try your solution.